# (How) can I delegate Google Apps access from one G account to another?

Tags: google-workspace, google-docs

How can I delegate Google Apps access from one G account to another?

It's [possible with Google Calendar](https://support.google.com/a/answer/117596?hl=en), but I haven't found a way to do it with Google Apps. I especially want it for documents and sheets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot delegate access to anything in Google Drive, as you would Gmail or Calendar.

The closest thing the 'manager' could do is create a folder and give the 'assistant' edit access to the folder. Everything within the folder should inherit the permissions of the folder and the 'assistant' can manage the 'manager's' docs.